# How to extract specific information from gdalinfo output?

Tags: bash, image, macos, grep, gdal

I'm using GDAL to get information about a satellite image. The `stdout` looks like the following:

```
$ gdalinfo B02.jp2
Driver: JPEG2000/JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1)
Files: B02.jp2
       B02.jp2.aux.xml
Size is 10980, 10980
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 15N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-93],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32615"]]
Origin = (600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
...
```

When I try to pull out a single line from `stdout`, it yields an error:

```
$ gdalinfo B02.jp2 | grep Origin
maximum number of samples exceeded (120560400 > 67108864)
error: cannot decode code stream
Origin = (600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000)
```

How can I extract information from the output (e.g. `Origin`) and assign it to a variable?

Comment: YOu need only `600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000` or the full string `Origin = (600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000)
`

Comment: Ideally, I would like to do something like `some_variable = "600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GNU grep` with its `PCRE` capabilities enabled by `-P` flag and store only the matching word within `braces()`

```
gdalinfo B02.jp2 2>/dev/null | grep -oP 'Origin = \(\K[^\)]+'
600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000
```

The `2>/dev/null` is for suppressing error messages from your command. To store it in a variable just do,

```
myOriginInfo="$(gdalinfo B02.jp2 2>/dev/null | grep -oP 'Origin = \(\K[^\)]+')"
printf "%s\n" "$myOriginInfo"
```

---

Since you don't have `GNU grep` installed, you can use this `POSIX` compatible `awk` expression to achieve your result,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[()]"}/Origin/{print $2}' file
600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000
```

and) in variable as

```
myOriginInfo="$(gdalinfo B02.jp2 2>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[()]"}/Origin/{print $2}')"
```

Comment: This produces the following output: `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHh....`. It does not appear to assign the text to the `myOriginInfo` variable.

Comment: @Borealis: It seems you don't have `GNU grep` installed, can you check output of `grep --version`?

Comment: That yields: `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: @Borealis: Ahh, missing the `GNU tools`, Are you allowed to install `GNU grep`? Are you on `Mac OS X`?

Comment: @Borealis: Refer my update using `awk` command to see if it worked.

Comment: fwiw, macOS (and for that matter FreeBSD) users have the option of installing `pcregrep` from MacPorts or HomeBrew. It's part of the [`pcre`](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=pcre) package.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip down your output to just the data you're interested in using bash parameter expansion, if you like.

```
$ x=$(gdalinfo B02.jp2 2>/dev/null | grep ^Origin)
$ x="${x#*(}"; x="${x%)}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000
```

Another fun option is to avoid using `grep` altogether and try to interpret your program output as fields:

```
declare -A a       # declare an associative array (requires bash 4)

while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  [[ -n "$value" ]] && a[${key% }]="${value# }"
done < <(gdalinfo B02.jp2 2>/dev/null)
```

The result of this will be an array, `a[]`, with which you can do things like:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[Origin]}"
(600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000)
```

You can of course strip off the parentheses using parameter expansion if you like.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[Origin]:1:$((${#a[Origin]}-2))}"
600000.000000000000000,5400000.000000000000000
```

Note that macOS has bash version 3 installed by default; if you want to use bash 4, you can install it using [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) or [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/).